# inserts not working mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-services

I'm having a problem while using a webtask as a backend web service to a static website. I'm using the web service to insert values to a mongodb database. The inserts are not returning any errors, but there is nothing inserting into the database. It just says 'worked' on the response. Here's the relevant code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  function savePage (page, db, cb){
   var doc = {
     pageSec: page
   };
 db.collection("page").insertOne(doc, function (err) {
   if(err) {return cb(err);}
    cb('worked');
 });
}
module.exports = function(context, cb){
 var section = context.query.section;
  if(section){
   MongoClient.connect(context.data.mongoUri, function(err, db) {
     if(err) {return cb(err);}
       savePage(section, db, function (err) {
        if(err){return cb(err);}
          cb(null);
        });
     });
 }
};
```

additionally, this is what mongodb returns in response to the insert

```
"details": {
"ok": 1,
"n": 1,
"lastOp": "6307485423539060737",
"electionId": "576dec4e2c52240b7a5bca5e"
},
"message": {
"parsed": true,
"index": 96,
"raw": {
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    96,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    163,
    69,
    36,
    3,
    5,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    8,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    60,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    16,
    111,
    107,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    16,
    110,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    17,
    108,
    97,
    115,
    116,
    79,
    112,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    147,
    176,
    136,
    87,
    7,
    101,
    108,
    101,
    99,
    116,
    105,
    111,
    110,
    73,
    100,
    0,
    87,
    109,
    236,
    78,
    44,
    82,
    36,
    11,
    122,
    91,
    202,
    94,
    0
  ]
},
"data": {
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    96,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    163,
    69,
    36,
    3,
    5,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    8,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    60,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    16,
    111,
    107,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    16,
    110,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    17,
    108,
    97,
    115,
    116,
    79,
    112,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    147,
    176,
    136,
    87,
    7,
    101,
    108,
    101,
    99,
    116,
    105,
    111,
    110,
    73,
    100,
    0,
    87,
    109,
    236,
    78,
    44,
    82,
    36,
    11,
    122,
    91,
    202,
    94,
    0
  ]
},
"bson": {},
"opts": {
  "promoteLongs": true
},
"length": 96,
"requestId": 52708771,
"responseTo": 5,
"responseFlags": 8,
"cursorId": "0",
"startingFrom": 0,
"numberReturned": 1,
"documents": [
  {
    "ok": 1,
    "n": 1,
    "lastOp": "6307485423539060737",
    "electionId": "576dec4e2c52240b7a5bca5e"
  }
],
"cursorNotFound": false,
"queryFailure": false,
"shardConfigStale": false,
"awaitCapable": true,
"promoteLongs": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I build my JSON object to sent to MongoDB, I always set the property name as string and it works.

```
 var doc = {
     "pageSec": page
   };
```

I don't see anything wrong in your code, so you can try this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I hadn't thought about setting the property name to a string. Unfortunately, the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you try with .insert()?, to discard options... although .insertOne() should work

Comment: Yeah I did try using .insert() as well. Unfortunately no change.